Blending an inflated equirectilinear image with another camera image
I'm struggling for this problem for one week. And I can't find a solution, or any approach. I'm wondering is that something impossible to do. I have provided all the information and trying to find a solution.
So I have the following fisheye distorted image, and I'm trying to enhance the fisheye inflated equirectilinear image.
The fish distorted image, is the following and the next is fisheye inflated equirectilinear image.
The purpose of this, I'm doing NERF and the output for the second image doesn't have all the details, and having a lot of bad pixels as shown in the figure.
So the point is to blend or whatever, to have better image in terms of details and clarity.
The engine that is used: https://github.com/fbriggs/lifecast_public/blob/main/nerf/source/lifecast_nerf_lib.cc#L1069
The paper that is describing their approach
https://lifecast.ai/baking_nerf_to_ldi.pdf
The equation for generating their distored image
This is the output from the script provided in the post

My approach:
Tried to generate the camera image to have similar distortion to target image, plus matching features, and add blending but the result is really not promising.
This is the output:

I'm looking for a C++ or a python solution(for trial). Here is my attempt and MVC
import cv2
import numpy as np

camera_image = cv2.imread('camera_0001 (1).tif')
undistorted_layer = cv2.imread('fused_bgra_000001.jpg')

height, width = camera_image.shape[:2]
undistorted_layer = cv2.resize(undistorted_layer, (width, height))
beta = 0.7
gamma = 3
S = 1.7  # Scaling factor
r90 = S * (width / 2)  # Adjust r90 with scaling

map_x = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.float32)
map_y = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.float32)

for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        nx = (x - width / 2) / r90
        ny = (y - height / 2) / r90
        r = np.sqrt(nx**2 + ny**2)
        
        # Apply the inflated equiangular transformation
        phi = (np.pi / 2) * (beta * r + (1 - beta) * (r ** gamma))
        
        if r != 0:
            new_x = (phi / r) * nx * r90 + width / 2
            new_y = (phi / r) * ny * r90 + height / 2
        else:
            new_x = width / 2
            new_y = height / 2
        
        map_x[y, x] = new_x
        map_y[y, x] = new_y

destination_image = cv2.remap(camera_image, map_x, map_y, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
cv2.imwrite('destination_image.png', destination_image)

sift = cv2.SIFT_create()

keypoints1, descriptors1 = sift.detectAndCompute(undistorted_layer, None)
keypoints2, descriptors2 = sift.detectAndCompute(destination_image, None)

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, k=2)

# Apply Lowe's ratio test
good_matches = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
        good_matches.append(m)

matched_image = cv2.drawMatches(undistorted_layer, keypoints1, destination_image, keypoints2, good_matches, None, flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
cv2.imwrite('matched_image.png', matched_image)

points1 = np.float32([keypoints1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good_matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
points2 = np.float32([keypoints2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good_matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

H, mask = cv2.findHomography(points1, points2, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)

aligned_layer = cv2.warpPerspective(undistorted_layer, H, (destination_image.shape[1], destination_image.shape[0]))

cv2.imwrite('aligned_layer.png', aligned_layer)

# Blend the images
blended = cv2.addWeighted(destination_image, 0.5, aligned_layer, 0.5, 0)

# Save and display the result
cv2.imwrite('blended_image.png', blended)
cv2.imshow('Blended Image', blended)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

This image is the one that I want to correct and to have more details using the camera image (the next image)

This is the input image

expected output: Notice the clarity and the details of the image compared to synsethized one from NERF
This is expected output that are two layers, I just need one layer of the two, as you see the image has higher details, no missing things


What does "inflated" mean?  Please clarify why your output is incorrect? Can you show a correct result?

@fmw42 inflated is a special type of their projection scheme. You can take more info in the paper. The correct result is just a clear picture using the original unflated camera image

By more detail do you mean more quality or just a bit more zoom to see the full circle of image. If the latter, have you tried adjusting your scale factor S? Or add a scale factor to your computation of new_x and new_y?

@fmw42 Thanks for your concern really appreciate that. I mean more quality, basically the same input image with the features of the circular output that I showed. I tried adding and adjusting scale factor S, and everything, couldn't get the same output desired at all

I do not see quality issues (to my eyes they look comparable). But the zoom is not showing the full circle, if that is also a concern. If you are concerned about quality, then I suspect it has to do with the linear interpolation you used in cv2.remap().  Try lanczos or cubic as higher order interpolation than linear.

What do you mean by "missing things" and "more details"?   What exactly is missing?

You might also try to resize your undistorted_layer with lanczos or cubic and see if that is better.

You have not posted your undistorted_layer. So one still cannot run your code! Minimal, Reproducible Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You also posted a PNG for your input, not your actual TIF!

@fmw42 Thanks for your input. Can I rephrase the problem ? Is it possible the input png, that I have posted to produce the fished eye distorted image that is shown in the output png ? I want to have the input camera image png and produce similar features (circular, fished eye).

Where do you get (or how did you derive) your equations for nx,ny and new_nx,new_ny?  I do not see those equations in the reference paper you're linked. You have not included eq 2 from the linked reference (you have not included theta).

What are the characteristics of your input?  Is that a perspective image? If so what field of view (or focal length)?

Why does the expected output have two layers?

@fmw42 I have tried my best to decipher the equations from the paper. Maybe I implemented it wrong. The input is a flat rectilinear image

@fmw42 Sorry about posting the two layers, it should be one layer, forgot to cut it

Suppose you do not do the eq 3 reference phi correction in your code.  Do you get a meaningful result for your conversion from the input to the fisheye output? I don't think even that would work properly due to lack of theta in your equations.

Please update your question to provide all the information above that I have requested.

Why have you asked about "inflated equirectangular"?  Is the reference not computing an "inflated equiangular" projection?

If you are concerned about quality, then the reference in computing to 12-bits, but are you not using 8-bit input or is your tiff actually 12 or 16 bits?

What is the purpose of the blend of two images?  Your code is failing in the generation of the inflated projection and possibly in just the computation of the equiangular projection without the phi correction.  So you have posted more than a minimum reproducible example. Cut out the code for the blending and concentrate first on computing a correct equiangle projection.  Then add the phi correction and see if that looks proper.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@fmw42 got your points. Many thanks. Is it possible to show just how to compute equiangular projection of the input image ?

That is something I think you need to work on. See the links that I showed. Also see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/286908844_Simple_fish-eye_calibration_method_with_accuracy_evaluation.  Search Google for other references with conversions.  Am I correct that your input is a perspective view and not an equiangular image. If so, then you are trying to get an equirectangular to fisheye, not an equiangular to fisheye as I expect they computed in your reference. So those equations do the apply to your case. Can you confirm?

If your input is a perspective image, then what is its field of view or focal length from the camera that took the image. You will need that information per the equations in the links that I sent to you.

The input is perspective image. FOV is 180 degrees.

That is a wide FOV for perspective.  How was the image captured -- what kind of camera or lens? Are there other parameters for the lens/camera?

@Andre Ahmed  Is that FOV of 180 deg measured along the diagonal of your image or the width?

@fmw42 The width

I do not believe that your input perspective image had a fov=180.  Please confirm again what lens fov you used.

@Andre Ahmed It does not visually look like 180 deg to me from side to side horizontally. I could be mistaken.

@Andre Ahmed Perspective does not support fov=180.

@fmw42 I really appreciate your hardworking, many thanks

@Andre Ahmed Perspective does not support fov=180. If your input is truly perspective, then what is the FOV of your lens (and image)

@Andre Ahmed Currently my code follows the equations from Wikipedia which need to know both the input and output FOV. A circular output the size of the image only occurs if both FOV are equal. But the output looses quality for FOV near 180 in the input perspective. I have not yet tried to fold in the code from your reference. I also do not know the type of fisheye view (or something else) which is used by your reference. He does not give a good mathematical description of the transformation. If you have any further information, please provide that.

@Andre Ahmed What kind of (input image) lens did you use? Do you know the range of focal lengths, if a wide angle lens and you do not know the FOV? Is there literature for your lens?

@Andre Ahmed I have worked out the changes needed to include/replace phi with the equation from your reference. But I need either the input FOV or input focal length to have an accurate output representing your input.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Here is some Python/OpenCV code to transform from perspective image to fisheye image.  Currently my code follows the equations from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens), which need both the input and output FOV. A circular output the size of the image only occurs if both FOVs are equal. But the output looses quality for FOV near 180 deg in the input perspective (as is expected, since perspective geometry fails at 180 deg)
Input:

import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

img = cv2.imread("camera_0001.png")

# get dimensions of input (source)
# output will be same dimensions
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# set input (source) perspective fov; must be less than 180 and gets very distorted as approach 180
ifov = 160

# set output (destination) fisheye fov
ofov = 180

# center of perspective and fisheye assumed to be center of image
xcent = w / 2
ycent = h / 2

# set background -- choices are "color" or "transparency"
background = "color"  # otherwise specify "transparency"

# set background color (for background=color)
bgcolor = (0,0,0)

# set up the x and y maps as float32
map_X = np.zeros((h, w), np.float32)
map_Y = np.zeros((h, w), np.float32)
mask = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)

# create map with the perspective and linear fisheye
#
# see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens
# note phi=fov/2 in below formulate; fov=field of view (aperture)
# note r=radius from dimension of image=N/2; N=width
# perspective: r=f*tan(phi); f=r/tan(phi); f=(N/2)/tan((fov/2)*(pi/180))=N/(2*tan(fov*pi/360))
# linear (equidistant) fisheye: r=f*phi; f=r/phi; f=(N/2)/((fov/2)*(pi/180))=N*180/(fov*pi)
# X,Y is source (perspective) and x,y is destination (fisheye)

# compute input (source) focal length from perspective equation and ifov
ifoc = w/(2*math.tan(ifov*math.pi/360))

# compute inverse of output (fisheye) focal length using ofov
ofocinv = (ofov*math.pi)/(w*180)

for y in range(h):
    # compute input (source) coords xx,yy as centered in range -1 to 1 from x,y
    yd = (y - ycent)
    for x in range(w):
        xd = (x - xcent)
        rd = math.hypot(xd,yd)
        if rd == 0:
            map_X[y, x] = x
            map_Y[y, x] = y
            mask[y,x] = 255
        elif rd > xcent:
            map_X[y, x] = x
            map_Y[y, x] = y
            mask[y,x] = 0
        else:
            # compute phiang for output (destination), but same phi as input
            phiang = ofocinv*rd
            
            # compute radius in input (perspective) from ifoc and phi
            rs = ifoc*math.tan(phiang)
            
            # compute source/input (perspective) X,Y ie map_X,map_Y coordinates from destination/output (fisheye) x,y coordinates
            # note: ternary equation good only if no rotation of fisheye output
            #(rs/rd)*
            map_X[y, x] = (rs/rd)*xd+xcent if rd != 0 else 0
            map_Y[y, x] = (rs/rd)*yd+ycent if rd != 0 else 0
            mask[y,x] = 255

# do the remap
result = cv2.remap(img, map_X, map_Y, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4, borderMode = cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=(0,0,0))

if background == "color":
    result[mask==0] = bgcolor
else: # transparency
    result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
    result[:,:,3] = mask
       
# save results
cv2.imwrite("camera_0001_fisheye.png", result)

# display images
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Fisheye for input FOV=120 and output FOV=180:

Fisheye for input FOV=160 and output FOV=180:

Fisheye for input FOV=160 and output FOV=160:

ADDITION
Here is the modified code for the Phi computation with the distortion arguments: scale (S), beta, gamma from the reference in the question.
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

img = cv2.imread("camera_0001.png")

# get dimensions of input (source)
# output will be same dimensions
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# set input (source) perspective fov; must be less than 180 deg and gets very distorted as approach 180
# note output (destination) fisheye fixed at 180
ifov = 160

# set phi angle distortion parameters
scale = 1.15
beta = 0.5
gamma = 3

# center of perspective and fisheye assumed to be center of image
xcent = w / 2
ycent = h / 2

# set background -- choices are "color" or "transparency"
background = "color"  # otherwise specify "transparency"

# set background color (for background=color)
bgcolor = (0,0,0)

# set up the x and y maps as float32
map_X = np.zeros((h, w), np.float32)
map_Y = np.zeros((h, w), np.float32)
mask = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)

# create map with the perspective and linear fisheye
# see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens

# note phi=fov/2 in below formulate for phi corresponding to fov; fov=field of view (aperture)
# note r=radius from dimension of image=N/2; N=width
# perspective: r=f*tan(phi); f=r/tan(phi); f=(N/2)/tan((fov/2)*(pi/180))=N/(2*tan(fov*pi/360))
# linear: r=f*phi; f=r/phi; f=(N/2)/((fov/2)*(pi/180))=N*180/(fov*pi)
# X,Y is source (perspective) and x,y is destination (fisheye)

# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78952264/blending-an-inflated-equirectilinear-image-with-another-camera-image?noredirect=1#comment139232795_78952264
# phi = (pi/2)*(beta*rprime + (1-beta)*rprime**gamma)
# where rprime = r/r90 and r90 = scale*width/2 and output FOV fixed at 180
# for beta=1 and scale=1, phi=(pi/2)*r/(2*w) = (pi*r/w)

# compute input (source) focal length from perspective equation and ifov
ifoc = w/(2*math.tan(ifov*math.pi/360))

# compute r90 = scale*w/2 for use later in rprime = rd/r90
r90 = scale*w/2

for y in range(h):
    # compute input (source) coords xx,yy as centered in range -1 to 1 from x,y
    yd = (y - ycent)
    for x in range(w):
        xd = (x - xcent)
        rd = math.hypot(xd,yd)
        if rd == 0:
            map_X[y, x] = xcent
            map_Y[y, x] = ycent
            mask[y,x] = 255
        elif rd > xcent:
            map_X[y, x] = 0
            map_Y[y, x] = 0
            mask[y,x] = 0
        else:
            # compute phiang for output (destination), but same phi as input
            rprime = rd/r90
            phiang = (math.pi/2) * ( beta*rprime + (1-beta)*(rprime)**gamma )
            
            # compute radius in input (perspective) from ifoc and phi
            rs = ifoc*math.tan(phiang)
            
            # compute source/input (perspective) X,Y ie map_X,map_Y coordinates from destination/output (fisheye) x,y coordinates
            # note: ternary equation good only if no rotation of fisheye output
            #(rs/rd)*
            map_X[y, x] = (rs/rd)*xd+xcent if rd != 0 else 0
            map_Y[y, x] = (rs/rd)*yd+ycent if rd != 0 else 0
            mask[y,x] = 255

# do the remap
result = cv2.remap(img, map_X, map_Y, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4, borderMode = cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=(0,0,0))

if background == "color":
    result[mask==0] = bgcolor
else: # transparency
    result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
    result[:,:,3] = mask
       
# save results
cv2.imwrite("camera_0001_fisheye2.png", result)

# display images
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Fisheye for ifov = 160, scale = 1.15, beta = 0.5, gamma = 3:

